# How to build sqlite3.dll with the command line in Windows with Visual C++?

Tags: sqlite, visual-c++

The source sqlite3.c has very few if at all, _declspec(dllexport) functions thus building it to a DLL in Windows produces an empty DLL!

My cmd line is:

`cl sqlite3.c -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll`

where is the export  file? How do I export the functions to the DLL?

Regards,
Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the `SQLITE_API` preprocessing symbol with the value `__declspec(dllexport)`, by adding the appropriate option to the command line (before the other options):

`cl sqlite3.c -DSQLITE_API=__declspec(dllexport) -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll`

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: How do I mark this topic as answered?